# Can't start/enable timesyncd on 20.04 LTS

Tags: ntp, systemd-timesyncd

When I try to I get this:

```
# systemctl enable systemd-timesyncd.service
Failed to enable unit: Unit file systemd-timesyncd.service does not exist.
```

NTP is installed:

```
# apt-get install ntp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ntp is already the newest version (1:4.2.8p12+dfsg-3ubuntu4.20.04.1).
```

Also:

```
# timedatectl set-ntp true
Failed to set ntp: NTP not supported
```

Answer (score 12):

As @Christian Ehrhard wrote. I installed "systemd-timesyncd" and set a local NTP server as target. After restarting the service it worked just fine.

```
sudo apt install systemd-timesyncd
sudo nano  /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf
```

set
NTP=<IP_of_your_NTP_Server>

```
systemctl restart systemd-timesyncd
```

result:

```
System clock synchronized: yes                        
NTP service: active
```

further help [here](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_20.04&p=ntp&f=3)

Maybe look into desynchronisation problem
[Blog: Fix Ubuntu TimeDateCTL NTP Sync No](https://www.tecklyfe.com/fix-ubuntu-timedatectl-ntp-sync-no/)

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately by "installing NTP" you did effectively remove `systemd-timesyncd`. I can understand that it can fly by too fast on an install/upgrade to notice - but those are mutually exclusive.
This is due to the fact that there can only be one NTP service reasonable working on a system.

So you could either `$ apt install systemd-timesyncd` which will remove NTP and make what you initially wanted work. Or alternatively if you want more sophisticated control of time sysncing then you should be aware that since 18.04 the supported and recommended package is `chrony`. Thereby the alternative is `$ apt install chrony` (which also will remove NTP).

See the bionic release notes which is when this switch happened:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#Chrony